# You have an error in your SQL syntax - truncates the name of the user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have checked through the other similar questions on this same topic, but even after going through them I cannot find what is wrong with my code.

1) I used this same code last week on a single-page php file and it worked. I have now split the file into multiple php files, which should have theoretically no impact at all. 
2) The error I receive is really odd (to me). When I input a comment using "Sally Test" as the name,  "Sally@test.com" as email and "testing 123" as the comment, I get this error:

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(author, email, ip, `date`, side, category, modscore, content)
>   VALUES ( 'Sally T' at line 1 "

It truncates "Sally Test" into just "Sally T" and I have no idea why that is.

Here is my code for the database processing (I'm using Dreamweaver):

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }
      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

          switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
              break;    
            case "long":
            case "int":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
              break;
            case "double":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
              break;
            case "date":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
              break;
            case "defined":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
              break;
          }
      return $theValue;
    }
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if (isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO " . $myname_sqltable ." (author, email, ip, `date`, side, category, modscore, content) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['author'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['ip'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['side'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['category'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['modscore'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['content'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_commenting_conn, $commenting_conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $commenting_conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

and here is the form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" name="contribute_form_side1-row0" action="/mozilla/index.php?">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="author">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" id="name_input_side1-row0" placeholder="Your Name">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email_input_side1-row0" placeholder="Your Email Address">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Content Input">Viewpoint</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content_input_side1-row0" rows="3" placeholder="Your perspective"></textarea>
              </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="**deleted**">
                                  <input type="hidden" name="date" value="2014-04-18 14:51:57">  
              <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="contribute_form_side1-row0">
              <input type="hidden" name="side" value="">
              <input type="hidden" name="category" value="0">
              <input type="hidden" name="modscore" value="0">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Why is it truncating the last name of the user (it happens with other names as well) and why is the form submission no longer working? I'm using almost duplicate code on the single-page version.

I also am learning the sqli stuff now, so in the longer run I do intend to replace all this. But for now, I would like to fix the code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "truncating" the name of the user; it's just that the error-message includes only a portion of the query, starting at the part where it noticed a problem. The quoted part happens to end right after the `T` in `Test`.

The actual problem seems to be that you never set `$myname_sqltable` to the name of a table, so your query begins with just `INSERT INTO (author, email,`.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh. 
Apologies, I set that earlier in the page but forgot to paste it in. Either way, it seems to work when I delete that variable and use the fixed table name. It might be a variable name clash somewhere in one of my other php pages. I'll check it out. Thanks!